# Error detected while processing function <SNR>70_SetVals:, E121: Undefined variable: g:pydiction_location -- error occured when hitting tab button

Tags: python, vim

I was writing a python file and I am getting this error when pressing the tab in insert mode in vim.

[image]

I am new to vim and I just copied someone's vimrc file. this is the vimrc file

```
"set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim' 
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/Pydiction'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'

call vundle#end()            
filetype plugin indent on
```

...........................
...........................
............................

```
let gidentifiers_from_tags_files = 1 
let g:ycm_use_ultisnips_completer = 1 
let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax = 1 
let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 1 
let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1     

let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1

    let mapleader=" "
map <leader>g  :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>

call togglebg#map("<F5>")


let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$', '\~$'] "ignore files in NERDTree

set nu


"python with virtualenv support
py3 << EOF
import os.path
import sys
import vim
if 'VIRTUA_ENV' in os.environ:
  project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
  sys.path.insert(0, project_base_dir)
  activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir,'bin/activate_this.py')
  execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
EOF


set splitbelow
set splitright

"split navigations
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>

" Enable folding with the spacebar
nnoremap <space> za
set foldlevel=99

autocmd FileType python set sw=4
autocmd FileType python set ts=4
autocmd FileType python set sts=4

highlight BadWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw match BadWhitespace /^\t\+/
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/



 au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw, set textwidth=100

au BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h set fileformat=unix

set encoding=utf-8

let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on

autocmd FileType python set autoindent

autocmd FileType python set foldmethod=indent
```

if you see any errors in vimrc please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Foreword:

The Pydiction plugin has not been maintained since 2014. YouCompleteMe, when configured correctly, should be able to do everything that Pydiction is able to do, and is still getting regular commits. You might consider just not using Pydiction.

Additionally, it's not usually a good idea to copy someones `.vimrc` wholesale, simply for reasons like this. Not saying that you **can't**, but if you do, you should take the time to read through the help documentation to make sure you understand what everything does.

However, if you really want to use Pydiction, a solution follows:

### Solution:

The plugin `vim-scripts/Pydiction` doesn't set `g:pydiction_location` by default. Since you're using Vundle with the default location, the included `complete-dict` should be located at `~/.vim/bundle/Pydiction/complete-dict`. You'll need to set `g:pydiction_location`:

```
let g:pydiction_location = expand('~/.vim/bundle/Pydiction/complete-dict')
```

The expand is required to expand `~` to `/home/<user`.